# How To Send GIFs From Directory In Discordpy

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to send gifs from my directory to discord.
How can i do that with:

```
@command(name="ban")

async def ban_gif(self, ctx):
```

[image: This is the directory path]

data/images/ban

Comment: [Discord Docx](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-mage)

Comment: Sending a gif is the same as sending any attachments in dpy.